# Moodle - Any way to get Access logs without plugin or direct DB?

Tags: api, moodle, moodle-api, lti

As an instructor, I want to be able pull raw data from the API to visualise a number of aspects of when my students are accessing my courses and materials. Is there any way I can pull this data? I could easily do it with a few lines of code in Canvas, so using Moodle feels like stepping back in time in terms of available APIs. I also teach a class on Learning Analytics, and students also don't have easy access to their own data.  Any ideas?

Comment: "using moodle feels like stepping back in time" - the issue isn't Moodle, the issue is that your institution won't give you access. Moodle is open source and fully customisable.

Comment: I guess what I was originally asking is how I can pull data for use in a Web App, not through a report and not directly from a database. I'd hoped that Moodle would have a general api to pull what students in a course looked at, much like Canvas' PageViews here - https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/users.html#PageView

Answer (score 1):

You can access user logs in a course by going to Participants then click on the user you want to track and you will be taken to their course profile. From there, you can choose any option in the "Reports" section. You will need to have the proper capabilities. The reports shown in the screenshot are from a site admin account.
[image: Reports section in user course profile]